# With CSS: how to do a radial wipe transition or animation to transparent bg

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a radial wipe (not a pie/circling effect) in which a bg color is sort of erased by a transparent round element scaling from 0 to 100% of viewport, revealing a bg image. Perhaps the two images will clarify.

[image: before animation]

### [image: during animation]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,

Whiskey T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone finds this question and wants to know how we pulled it off:

My hat's off to the designer who suggested using an svg element with the baby blue background color, and a donut hole cut out of the center. I discovered the need therefore to add a mask element to cover the hole, which, via css transitions, is crossfaded with the darker blue circle and timed carefully so that the hole is never exposed and thus the background image is not exposed. Finally the donut svg is transitioned via scale to several times the default size (100%, 100%) so that it expands outward, exposing the bg image.